# Stubbing child components in Ember component test

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a deeply nested component structure and I don't want to stub the dependencies (mainly services and ajax calls) of all the child components and their child components. Is there a way to inject a stub like `Ember.Component.create({})` into the container to replace the real one for that test. It seems like it should be possible but I can't seem to figure out the syntax or find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After experimenting a bit more, it turned out to be really simple:

```
moduleForComponent('test-component', 'Integration | Component | test', {
    integration: true,
    beforeEach: function () {
        this.owner.register('component:test-component2', Ember.Component.extend());
    }
});
```

Now `{{test-component2}}` inside `{{test-component}}` is going to be a default Ember component.

To also stub the templates add `this.owner.register('template:components/test-component2', '')` in the `beforeEach` callback.

For *Ember 2* use `this.register(...)` instead of `this.owner.register(...)`.

**Edit: Updates (Ember 3 syntax, template stub) based on comments**

Comment: You might want to stub its template too `this.register('template:components/test-componet2', '')`

Comment: In Ember 3.x, it is: `this.owner.register(...)`